# What does Preserve sharing means in lazy Streams?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm following the Functional Programming in Scala book. Here is the code snippet from Stream definition and functions to construct `constant` using smart constructor and using `unfold`:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A]
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, tl: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
  def cons[A](h: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = h
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }
  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = cons(a, constant(a))

  def unfold[A, S](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A, S)]): Stream[A] =
    f(z).fold(empty[A])(x => cons(x._1, unfold(x._2)(f)))

  def constantViaUnfold[A](a: A): Stream[A] = unfold(a)(x => Some((x, x)))
}
```

There is a footnote saying that:

> Using `unfold` to define `constant` means that we won't get sharing as in the recursive definition. The recursive definition consumes constant memory even if we keep a reference to it around while traversing it, while the unfold-based implementation does not. Preserving sharing isn’t something we usually rely on when programming with streams, since it’s extremely delicate and not tracked by the types. For instance, sharing is destroyed when calling even `xs.map(x => x).`

What do the authors mean when saying that we are not getting *sharing*? What exactly is shared and why it's not preserved in `unfold` version? Also the sentence about constant memory consumption is not clear as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you create a new list like that:

```
val n0 = Nil       //List()
val n1 = 1 :: n0   //List(1)
val n2 = 2 :: n1   //List(2,1)
val n3 = 3 :: n2   //List(3,2,1)
```

If you build a list like that, it's easy to notice that *n3* is really *n2* with *3* prepended and *n2* is just *n1* with *2* prepended, etc. So reference to *1* is **shared** by *n1*, *n2* and *n3* and reference to *2* is shared by *n2* and
*n2*, etc. 
You could write it also like:

```
Cons(3, Cons(2, Cons(1, Nil)))
```

This is also the case in an example from *FPinS* when you create *Stream* recursively. You *Stream* is built from nested *Cons* and every substream shares elements with its parent. So when the next *Stream* is created it just wraps old one inside *Cons* with the new element. But since *Stream* is lazy all this building of *Cons* hierarchy will be only done if you *materialize* it, for example by calling **toList**.

Building stream like that gives you also constant memory consumption because creating the next stream from previous will only cost memory for a new element.

And why it is not a case with `unfold`? Because it builds Stream "other way around". So it goes like:

```
Cons(x, next_iteration_of_unfold)                    //1st iteration
Cons(x, Cons(x, next_iteration_of_unfold))           //2nd iteration
Cons(x, Cons(x, Cons(x, next_iteration_of_unfold)))  //3rd iteration, etc.
```

So as you can see nothing can be shared.

**EDIT:**

You can see how the materialized stream looks by calling `take` on final [implementation](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala) on the book and adding `toString` to `Cons`:

```
override def toString: String = s"Cons(${h()}, ${tl()})"
```

And then:

```
Stream.ones.take(3)
```

You will see:

```
Cons(1, Cons(1, Cons(1, Empty)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I will provide the original book's (2014 year edition) quote to avoid confusion :

> Using unfold to define constant and ones means that we don’t get sharing as in the recursive definition
>   **val ones: Stream[Int] = cons(1, ones)**. The recursive definition consumes constant memory even if we
>   keep a reference to it around while traversing it, while the unfold-based implementation does not. Preserving sharing isn’t something we usually rely on when programming with streams, since it’s extremely delicate
>   and not tracked by the types. For instance, sharing is destroyed when calling even xs.map(x => x).

As you can see the problem is a bit different here now. It's about reusing `Cons` instance, so `Stream` just reference to itself here.

So it was supposed by the author to have implementation like this:

```
//Imp1
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = {
   lazy val ones: Stream[A] = cons(a, ones)
   ones
}
```

instead of just

```
//Imp2
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = cons(a, constant(a))
```

As you can see `Imp1` creates only one instance of `Cons` for entire stream. `Imp2` and `unfold` version from your example generate new `Cons` on every next call instead, so both methods generate streams that don't share `Cons` instance.

Comment: I get the `ones` re-usage of reference. But your `Imp1` doesn't compile for me with `forward reference extends over definition of value ones` message. does it mean that constant cannot be defined with recursive definition or am I missing something?

Comment: try to change `val` to `lazy val`. non-lazy-val works if you define `once` as class field instead of local variable.

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes more sense for me. I was hesitating to ask such question but I'm glad I did)

Comment: Try to materialize stream with take(4).toList. There will bo not a single Cons, but more.

Comment: implementation form the book is just a "toy" stream. there is not `take` in there, so I suppose that the author just wanted to show recursive `Cons` sharing aspect.

Comment: Not really, there is full version of book's Stream on github. I'm away from keyboard right now so its hard for me to paste link, but you can google it.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala) you go :)

Comment: you are right. But anyway.. The quote from the book is exactly about `Cons` sharing (or stream instance sharing).  As it says directly about it: `the recursive definition val ones: Stream[Int] = cons(1, ones)` . Github code contains this line as well.. but not as a method.

Comment: Yes, and ones is recursive, but it's not strict. Please see my edit.

Comment: I think you missed that `Cons` arguments are not strict.

Comment: you are right. materialization ruins everything) But it's still sharing `Cons` and its "value" before the materialization.